# How does the knitr language engine for Python in RMarkdown keep track of variables across code chunks?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, reticulate

I was looking at the source code of knitr in order to better understand how the language engines work, and it seems that evaluating code in a single chunk is a relatively simple matter, but what I have trouble understanding is how it is possible for the Python chunks to call the variables across chunks. I get the impression [from earlier packages by Yihui](https://github.com/yihui/runr) that attempts were made to do this with sockets, but it seems that the current code for both reticulate and knitr does not contain code for sockets, hence my question.

Answer (score 1):

This is done through the **reticulate** package instead of **runr**. You may see [Section 2.7.1](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/language-engines.html#python) of the *R Markdown Definitive Guide* for details.

P.S. **runr** was a very early experiment and never officially used in **knitr**.